# XPath evalute multiple values with starts_with()

Tags: xpath

Having XML with book nodes and each book can have multiple authors. How do I find books with at least one author starting with letter E?

```
for $book in /library/book[starts-with(author,'E')]
return $book
```

This doesnt seem to work with multiple authors...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates can be nested.

```
for $book in /library/book[author[starts-with(., 'E')]]
return $book
```

or, more defensively:

```
for $book in /library/book[author[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'E')]]
return $book
```